# Attempting to use VB.NET Lambda instead of iterator

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am fairly certain that I could perform the below code using a Lambda expression in VB.NET, but I can't seem to find an example of doing so.  Mt attempts to do this have been fruitless.

I'm just iterating through the Me.Controls collection, and then doing two nested If's (which could be one that is joined with an AndAlso instead)...and if the condition matches, invoke the .Controls.Clear() method on the object.

```
    For Each C As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf C Is GroupBox Then
            If C.Name.StartsWith("grpScreen") Then
                CType(C, GroupBox).Controls.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you for your help,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
     Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)() _
       .Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith("grpScreen")) _
       .ToList() _
       .ForEach(Sub(c) c.Controls.Clear())
```